# Combine multiple cells from one sheet to calendar in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, calendar

I am trying to make an organising sheet that is connected to a calendar. I want to combine multiple cells from Sheet 1 into one single cell in Sheet 2 (the calendar). I also want it to update automatically whenever I put in new information into Sheet 1. I have already arranged the organising sheet monthly, as well as the calendar. All the information in Sheet 1 is connected to a particular date.

So for example,
I want to export A1 through C1 from Sheet 1 into the cell for the 20th of July 2022 in Sheet 2. When I move on to A2 through C2 from Sheet 1, I want the information to go into the cell with the same date in Sheet 2 as Sheet 1.

Is it impossible? Or do I have to export it to a completely empty sheet and then organise that sheet by date instead?

I have tried using the `=FILTER(ARRAYFORMULA(Sheet1!B1:B&" "&Sheet1!C1:C&" "&Sheet1!D1:D); Sheet1!A1:A=A1)` but I cannot make it work.

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se] What web app are you using? Also, please show what you have tried and add brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Hi, welcome to WebApps. Please keep in mind that we can't see your spreadsheet. Your description makes complete sense because you can see your data and the outcome that you want From "here", we don't know whether there is already data on sheet2, what does sheet 1 look like, or how the outcome on sheet2 will look. You said _export_ and you reference `filter`, but it's not clear whether you are trying to create permanent changes on Sheet1 and/or Sheet2. Please edit your question to supply sample data for both sheets and an example of a successful outcome.